# Getting data from Police.uk with PHP and display them on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am implementing a dashboard, that has to get data from police.uk API and display them on Google Maps. 
The request to the API(link to the API: http://data.police.uk/docs/) is a URL like http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2013-01  and the response is JSON data, that are displayed on Google Maps. There is a similar question for that on Stackoverflow, but they use Spring MVC controllers. However, I am interested in how can I get these data and display them on Google Maps with PHP.  Any suggestions on that? I attach my code for the Google Map.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var latlng;
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.5500, 2.4333);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 9,
  center: latlng
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}

var take;
function codeLatLong() {
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    take = map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
       center: results[0].geometry.location,
       radius:20000,
       strokeColor:"#0000FF",
       strokeOpacity:0.8,
       strokeWeight:2,
       fillColor:"#0000FF",
       fillOpacity:0.4
    });

    myCity.setMap(map);


  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
}
//Calling the JSON data from the website with an example
$.getJSON( "http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2013-01", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
});

$( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
<div>
<input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder = "Enter address, or postcode">
<input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeLatLong()">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not request the json data directly from javascipt? If you get the data with a PHP script you still need to send it back to the javascript code that draws the map.

Comment: I'm new to JSON and PHP and did not know that. Let me see if I can get somewhere with that. Thanks!

Comment: Still nothing. I used the .getJSON() method to display the data, but I don't get something back. If you could see my edit and post your suggestions, that would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code with the URL from the initial question. And get the results expected. Here is my test snippet.

```
$.getJSON( "http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2013-01", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val.location.street.name + " (lat: " + val.location.latitude + ", long: " + val.location.longitude + ") </li>" );
});

$( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Display markers on the map is quite easy. More info can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

```
$.getJSON( "http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2013-01", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(val.location.latitude,val.location.longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: val.location.street.name
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this works for me as well. What I cannot figure out, is how to display them on the map. Thanks again for your help.